# Hierarchy table selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that holds locations, for, let's say, a Prison.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [LocationTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GeoLocation] [geometry] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [pk_location] PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Data file insert here:
[data.sql file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p9xz35ihexrxux/Data.sql?dl=0)
When ParentID is null, that's the root node of the system.

In the data, we may have a Prison (TypeID = 5), a Building (TypeID=6), a floor, a cell and a bed. The parent ID is the location in which the current location is located.

I created a view allowing for easy access to this table.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwLocations]
AS

 WITH MyLocation 
 AS (
        SELECT  ParentID, 
                ID, 
                Name, 
                0 AS LevelNo, 
                CAST(CAST(LocationTypeID AS VARCHAR) + '|' + Name AS VARCHAR(512)) AS SORT_PATH
        FROM dbo.Location AS A
        WHERE        (ParentID IS NULL)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  C.ParentID, 
                C.ID, 
                C.Name, 
                MyLocation_1.LevelNo + 1 AS Expr1, 
                CAST(MyLocation_1.SORT_PATH + '//' + CAST(C.LocationTypeID AS VARCHAR) + '|' + C.Name AS VARCHAR(512)) AS SORT_PATH
        FROM  dbo.Location AS C 
        INNER JOIN MyLocation AS MyLocation_1 
            ON MyLocation_1.ID = C.ParentID
    )
    SELECT  ISNULL(ID, -999) AS LocationID, 
            ParentID, 
            LevelNo AS LevelNumber, 
            SORT_PATH AS FullPath, 
            Name AS Description
    FROM   MyLocation AS ML
GO
```

And this is working well, and efficiently for all cases. The developer gets a string back if they want to break it into each component. For example, I return a string:

5|The Prison//6|P 1//7|P 1//8|1//9|01//10|01

Which they then split on the '//' to get

5|The Prison
6|P 1
7|P 1
8|1
9|01
10|01

Which means, ID 5 means its a Prison, ID 6 means it's a building, ID 7 is a section, ID 8 is a floor, 9 is a Cell and 10 is a bed.

They do that in the code.

Problem is, they want to be able to sort by Floor, for example. Which, I can't do. What I need to do, somehow, is add extra columns for each row, called 'Prison', 'Building'... etc, and populate them.

So a few may be null, because if the location is a Floor, for example, then the Prison, Building, section and floor columns will have data, but the rest will be null.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried substringing the field into seperate fields, storing that as a view, and then sorting the new floor column in the view?

Comment: @JLB - I was going to try that, but can that still be done in a view? Would it be a 'CASE' statement? But even if it was, I'm not sure how I can use a CASE statement, to populate different columns. Or would the CASE be in the final select, and there may be 5 CASES statements - one for each column? Or are you saying two views, this this one being the primary data extraction, and then some sorting in the 2nd view - somehow?

Comment: If I'm reading the request correctly, you're asking for a breadth-first search (BFS) of your hierarchy. If so, provide some sample data (preferably in a format where I can copy/paste it into SSMS and get a table out of it) and I can provide code that will give you a BFS ordered result set.

Comment: Thanks @Ben I've linked a file after the table create. Hopefully you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the HierarchyID data type. I'm going to cut to the chase:

```
alter table dbo.Location add 
    [Path] hierarchyid null, 
    [Level] as [Path].GetLevel() persisted;

WITH MyLocation AS (
    SELECT  ParentID, 
            ID, 
            Name, 

            cast(concat('/', ID, '/') as varchar(1000)) as [Path]
    FROM dbo.Location AS A
    WHERE        (ParentID IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  C.ParentID, 
            C.ID, 
            C.Name, 
            cast(concat(p.[Path], c.ID, '/') as varchar(1000)) as [Path]
    FROM  dbo.Location AS C 
    INNER JOIN MyLocation AS p 
        ON p.ID = C.ParentID
)
update l
set [Path] = ml.[Path]
from dbo.Location as l
join MyLocation as ml
    on l.ID = ml.ID
GO
```

What I've done here is add a column of HierarchyID to your table. This will allow me to store the path all the way to the ultimate ancestor (in your case, the Prison) and to query for ancestors along the path efficiently.

Next, a table-valued function.

```
create function dbo.tvf_PivotHierarchy(@id int)
returns table
as return

    select ID,
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6]  
    from (
        select p.ID, l.[Description], l.[Level]
        from dbo.Location as l
        join dbo.Location as p
            on p.[Path].IsDescendantOf(l.[Path]) = 1
        where p.ID = @id
    ) as p
    pivot (
        max(Description)
        for [Level] in (
            [1],
            [2],
            [3],
            [4],
            [5],
            [6]
        )
    ) as pvt;
go
```

Sample usage:

```
with data as (
    select * from (values
        (67),
        (115)
    ) as x(ID)
)
select * 
from data as d
join dbo.Location as l
    on d.ID = l.ID
cross apply dbo.tvf_PivotHierarchy(l.ID);
```

All that's happening here is that, for a given ID, I'm finding all records that are ancestors of that record and running it through a simple pivot.

Now, if you want to sort a particular way, you've got options. If you want to sort in a depth-first manner (i.e. prison, building, all floors in that building, next building, etc), throw an `order by [Path]` on that last query; if you want to do breadth-first (i.e. prison, , , etc), do `order by [Level], [Path]`.

I'm being sloppy and doing things like `select *` and not naming the columns in the pivot something more meaningful partly because the result sets are more illustrative of what's going on and partly because I'm lazy. You should clean this up for production use should you choose to use it.

Comment: Wow @Ben! This looks very interesting. I'm going to give it a go. So many new concepts there. Thanks. I'll report back.

Comment: This looks to work really well! I'm not quite understanding if there is a way to insert the row, and not perform the update. Our scripts that populate the Location are currently done via a migration from a source system. Is there a way to populate the Path and Level when inserting the rows?

Comment: Yes. You have two scenarios: one where you know the ID before insert and one where you don't. In the former, you need to do the insert to get the identity value and then do a post facto update once you have it. In the latter case, you can do it all at once. Either way, you can get the Path by grin the parent's Path and appending the child's ID and a taking slash onto it. Level is a computed column so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Ben - so it's valid to say that my current migration will remain as is, as the IDs are identity columns, and after the location table is populated, I can perform that update. Additionally, every time we add a new Location row, regardless of the level, the Update should be performed to update the levels and paths?

Comment: More or less. Depending on how you're inserting your data (bulk or more OLTP), you have the ability to set the Path after each insert. That is, you can calculate the HierarchyID for recently inserted rows (i.e. rows `where [Path] is null`) by doing the recursive CTE backwards (i.e. from leaf to root). Or you can wait until the end, it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks Ben - I can perform the post update (Setting Level/path) after the migration - that's perfectly acceptable. But I'm unsure of the process when we add a new location row during operation of the system. Would I add the new location row, and then run that UPDATE? Or is there a way to do this seamlessly? Maybe a trigger on Update/Insert?

Comment: If you're adding a single row, you can calculate the Path assuming that the ParentID is known. It's induction in the mathematical sense: you can derive level n+1 assuming that you know n. Now, for my money, I like doing such things in a stored procedure and gating the insert operation through that. But you could do it in a trigger as well. If you ever update a row's ParentID, you'll need to update not only that row's Path but all of its children as well.

Comment: I've walked into a speed issue now, unfortunately. Returning 700 rows is taking 5 seconds. I'll create a new question for this.

Comment: Did you index your hierarchy column? That should help if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with any solution like this (and you're not the first to try) is without special features in the database engine, you can't represent an arbitrarily-deep tree...anything on level 1 is going to be (should be) joined to the parent with a node of 0, anything on level 2 should be joined to a parent on level 1, etc., etc.  So it's more than trying to sorting on the floor (which, quite honestly, should just be an ORDER BY at the end of the view select) but more fundamentally you can't traverse the tree unless you have a join for every possible level.

Simplify this as "trees cannot be stored in a relational database"